# Linear map with Distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A: \Bbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$ be a linear transformation with eigenvalues $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{9}{5}$.

Then how to prove there exist a non- zero vector $v \in \Bbb{R}^2$ such that $\vert \vert Av \vert \vert=\vert \vert v \vert \vert$ ?

I know A has distinct eigenvalues, so diagonalizable. How to proceed further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By continuity. There is a vector $v$ with norm $1$ such that $Av=\frac95v$ and there is a vector $w$ with norm $1$ such that $Aw=\frac23w$. Consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&t&\mapsto&\dfrac{\left\|A\bigl((1-t)v+tw\bigr)\right\|}{\|(1-t)v+tw\|},\end{array}$$Since $f(0)=\frac95$ and $f(1)=\frac23$, $f(t)=1$ for some $t\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Actually, $Av=\frac{9}{5} v$ means $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$. what is the necessity that norm v equal to 1?

Comment: @LearningMathematics It isn't. But it *is* necessary that $v\neq0$ for my argument to work and I thought that taking $\|v\|=1$ was a natural choice. But you can replace “with norm $1$” with “different from $0$” and my answer will still work.

Comment: How to show that there is no non-zero vector $v$ such that $||Av||>2||v||$? Also, no non-zero vector $v$ with $||Av||<\frac12||v||$?

Comment: You *don't* prove it, since it is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v:=\lambda e_{2/3}+\mu e_{9/5}$ where $e_a$ denotes the Eigenvectors, which are orthogonal.

Then enforce

$$\|v\|^2=\lambda^2+\mu^2=1$$ and $$\|Av\|^2=\frac49\lambda^2+\frac{81}{25}\mu^2=1.$$

This system has positive solutions in $\lambda^2,\mu^2$.

Comment: How do we know that these eigenvectors are orthogonal?

Comment: @Silent: Eigenvectors *are* orthogonal.

Comment: You mean generally they are orthogonal? [I don't think so.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vs2sRvSzA3o) I see that they are orthogonal for symmetric matrices.